# Gizmo faces in different direction based on faces

Tags: edit-mode, normals

I am editing a 3d object made by a friend, for a game jam. Said friend is not very experienced in 3d and I am trying to tidy up his mesh. I come from Cinema 4d and am trying out blender. What I noticed were that many of the faces themselves had weird shininess or gradient to them, similar to phong issues iirc.

After looking on the internet for a while, i discovered the "Clear custom split normals" in the geometry data. This helped a lot to make it look better. It still renders weird, with the orientations of the normals being rotated in different orientations for the X and Y directions.

Is there any easy way to tidy this up?
(The easy way is of course to just model it from scratch, but I became curious as to what was causing this and wanted to know in case I ran across it myself)

[image: Face 1]

[image: Face 2]

[image: Previs]

[image]

Comment: Hello could you please share your object? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: In Edit mode, select All (A key) then Shift-N to recalculate the normals.

Comment: Hi. Tried to add the blender-file. See if it works. Already recalculated the normals, which did not help.

Comment: Simply do a right click > Shade Smooth?

Comment: That works wonders. Though, I still wonder how to set the rotation of the normals along their Z axis. And if you can align them all facing the same way. The Z will always point out at a 90 degree from the face it is on, but the rotation around that axis is all messed up.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, face normal will always be 90° to the face, note that the split normals, that determine the shading, are another thing

Comment: If you look at the first 2 screenshots you see that the gizmo has a different orientation on the faces in image 1 to image 2. The XY plane is rotated 90 degrees counter clockwise. As mentioned this is not something I have modelled, and when I tried modelling the same shape, the rotation of those X and Y arrows behaved like I expected, and had the same rotation.